# Laravel Eloquent, multi-depth dot notation using withTrashed() returning null relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm having trouble using withTrashed() when using multi depth dot notation.

Everything works well when:

```
with(['trials.activity' => function ($q) { $q->withTrashed(); }])->
```

dd() returns:

```
#relations: array:1 [▼
    "activity" => Activity {#1139 ▶}
  ]
```

However, when adding multi depth notation, the deleted row's relationships do not appear, for example:

```
with(['trials.activity.goalcategories.goals.scoretype' => function ($q) { $q->withTrashed(); }])->
```

dd() returns:

```
#relations: array:1 [▼
    "activity" => null
  ]
```

The activity has the deleted row, but it would be good to include the relationships if rows are also deleted in depth of dot notation, if possible.

Is there a way to make it work with the closure, or is there some work around?

Comment: What does "not seem to work" mean?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Err, that wasn't very descriptive, I edited the question and added some dd response excerpts. Thank you.

Comment: Which relationship has deleted rows?

Comment: @TravisBritz the activity relationship has the deleted rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently applying `withTrashed()` to the `scoretype` relationship.

Use this instead:

```php
->with(['trials.activity' => function ($q) {
    $q->withTrashed();
}, 'trials.activity.goalcategories.goals.scoretype']);
```

Answer (score 1):

The callback is run on the last in the list of relationships, so you need to break it up in the middle:

```php
->with(['trials.activity' => function ($q) {
        $q->withTrashed()
          ->with(['goalcategories.goals.scoretype']);
}])
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer as well, worked perfectly. I had to give answer to Jonas as he answered a few minutes earlier. I appreciate your time though, thank you.

Comment: @greebo3 no problem! There is a difference between our answers however, so you might want to double check that theirs also has all of the data you expected. I'm not 100% sure of the behavior when two different relationships are combined in the way Jonas demonstrated, which is why I included another answer.